# Segmentation fault and address sanitizer

Tags: c, fgets, strtok, segmentation-fault, address-sanitizer

something strange happens in my code.
I'm using `fgets` to get each line of a file and then I use `strtok` to parse it. using Ubuntu, if I compile using `gcc -o name name.c`, it gives me `segmentation fault`. If I compile using `-fsanitize=address`, the code runs perfectly without any segv. What could be the problem?

the code is:

```
char* input;
fgets(input, 1000, stdin);
tok=strtok(input, pars);
```

but it looks like it stops at `fgets`.

Comment: The address sanitizer is able to detect only some kinds of undefined behavior. Enabling the ASAN may also modify the produced code in such a way that the UB does not trigger a segmentation fault anymore. Thus a [repro] to answer more specifically would be necessary.

Comment: okay, i use
char* input;
fgets(input, 1000, stdin);
tok=strtok(input, pars);
but it looks like it stops at the fgets

Comment: That is not a [repro]. Please read the link again and make sure your example code is *complete* and *reproducible*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the problem?

Your line

```
char* input;
```

just declares a pointer to `char` without assigning an address to it. Where do you think will it point at?

Then you want to

```
fgets(input, 1000, stdin);
```

for at most 999 characters, but you never provide the space for them.

If you change the first line to

```
char input[1000];
```

it will work without segmentation error.

Answer (score 0):

in your code it is  obvious that you want to get a string by using fgets, what the compiler  thinks is that the pointer will be used to point at an address, but instead you use it to point at a string causing the segv

the proper approach is this

```
char *input = malloc(<any size you want>);
fgets(input, <the size you want>, <the stream you want to get from>);
```

and this approach should solve your problem

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the pointer points to, but instead is because he didn't allocate memory for the pointer first. Also, to point to a string is to point to an address, so your first sentence doesn't really make sense.